# How to query critical JSON into ionic

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I received the JSON response from the server mentioned below.

```
{
  "employeeId": null,
  "id": "DB06442E-2993-4FE8-B496-5A0CF61C8342",
  "message": null,
  "objects": [
    {
      "Children": [],
      "Fields": [
        {
          "Key": "CallID",
          "Value": 1000
        },
        {
          "Key": "CallDate",
          "Value": "Sep 9 2016 10:14AM"
        },
        {
          "Key": "ClientName",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Key": "AssetName",
          "Value": "Automatic Cold Cranking Simulator"
        },
        {
          "Key": "CallCategory",
          "Value": "Corrective Maintenance"
        }
      ],
      "Type": 8
    },
    {
      "Children": [],
      "Fields": [
        {
          "Key": "CallID",
          "Value": 1000
        },
        {
          "Key": "CallDate",
          "Value": "Sep 9 2016 10:20AM"
        },
        {
          "Key": "ClientName",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Key": "AssetName",
          "Value": "Auto Mini Pour Point Tester "
        },
        {
          "Key": "CallCategory",
          "Value": "Preventive Maintenance"
        }
      ],
      "Type": 8
    },
    {
      "Children": [],
      "Fields": [
        {
          "Key": "CallID",
          "Value": 1000
        },
        {
          "Key": "CallDate",
          "Value": "Sep 9 2016 10:23AM"
        },
        {
          "Key": "ClientName",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Key": "AssetName",
          "Value": "Balance - Citizon CX 220"
        },
        {
          "Key": "CallCategory",
          "Value": "Calibration"
        }
      ],
      "Type": 8
    },
    {
      "Children": [],
      "Fields": [
        {
          "Key": "CallID",
          "Value": 1001
        },
        {
          "Key": "CallDate",
          "Value": "Sep 9 2016 10:26AM"
        },
        {
          "Key": "ClientName",
          "Value": ""
        },
        {
          "Key": "AssetName",
          "Value": "Others"
        },
        {
          "Key": "CallCategory",
          "Value": "Installation"
        }
      ],
      "Type": 8
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

Can you please explain me bit more as per my json structure.

myhtml.html

```
<ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="item in callItems" type="item-text-wrap" ng-click="doTask()">

                        <h3 style="color:black;">{{item.CallID}}</h3>
                        <h3 style="color:black;">{{item.CallDate}}</h3>
                        <p style="color:black;">{{item.ClientName}}</p>
                        <p style="color:black;">{{item.AssetName}}</p>
                        <p style="color:black;">{{item.CallCategory}}</p>

            </ion-item>
```

myjs.js

```
$http.post("http://testCrm.com/GetAllObjects",
                       {"objectId":null,"objects":null,"searchParams":null,"sessionId":"DB06442E-2993-4FE8-B496-5A0CF61C8342","type":8})
            .success(function(data) {
                     alert("SUCCESS!");

                     $rootScope.callItems = data;
                     console.log($rootScope.callItems);

                     })
            .error(function(data) {
                   alert("ERROR");
                   alert(data);
                   });
```

As per my code I can able to get the response But How can i parse the value in View ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow this also

```
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in item.Fields">

           <h3 style="color:black;">  {{value.Value}}</h3>

        </div>
      <button ng-click=something($index,item.Fields[0].Value)>check it</button>
</div>
```

**js**
add the below function and see u will get a alert with index

```
$scope.something=function(a,b){
  alert(a);//alerts index
 alert(b);//alerts CaalID of that index
}
```

[working codepen](http://codepen.io/sai525/pen/YGymLJ)

[new requirments](http://codepen.io/sai525/pen/YGymLJ)

Comment: short n sweet @Chowdary

Comment: oh ya thank you....but i missed your requirement that u need 2 h3 and rest are p tags.i am banging my head to meet that

Comment: Hi - As per our above discussion I can able to populate the values in the UI. Actually I show case the mentioned response in the List view, My doubt is how can i get the selected index and selected cell CallID as per json? is it possible to get the values in the controller?

Comment: yes u can....u need some event like click() with in that u can pass any info u want to the controller

Comment: updated my answe with your current requirement check it

Comment: Thanks much @Sa E Chowdary - As per your guidance I parse the json and show case it into the UI as per list view. Now While i clicking the list view cell I want to get the selected json index and its CallID is it possible ?

Comment: index u can get it as i shown.....i am thinking about that call id i will update asap

Comment: updated with your requiremnts....worked for me please check with your part

Comment: Thanks much @Sa E Chowdary - Kudos

Comment: Sorry again to open this question - Do you ve any idea about getting all Call_ID into select tag ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127657/discussion-between-shiv-suthan-m-and-sa-e-chowdary).

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://plnkr.co/edit/tYIYD2SQA9HObjOYWsq6?p=preview) might not be the best solution but it's a working demo. i think you need to change the json object structure again and re create it according to your requirement.

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in callItems.objects">
      <div ng-repeat="fi in item" >
        <div ng-repeat="kk in fi">
          <h3 style="color:black;" ng-if="kk.Key == 'CallID'">{{kk.Value}}</h3>
          <h3 style="color:black;" ng-if="kk.Key == 'CallDate'">{{kk.Value}}</h3>
          <h3 style="color:black;" ng-if="kk.Key == 'ClientName'">{{kk.Value}}</h3>
          <h3 style="color:black;" ng-if="kk.Key == 'AssetName'">{{kk.Value}}</h3>
          <h3 style="color:black;" ng-if="kk.Key == 'CallCategory'">{{kk.Value}}</h3>
        </div> 
      </div>
```